# Simple firebase express request doesn't work

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed the node.js guide to setting up a firebase app. This is the code in my `app.js` file. All of the information is correct, but I do not get a value from snapshot key. In fact, `storesRef.once()` never prints the "test". No errors are being thrown so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

```
// init firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: {
    projectId: "wrapper",
    clientEmail: "wrapper@wrapper.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMY KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  },
  databaseURL: "https://wrapper.firebaseio.com"
});

// test get 
var db = firebase.database();
var storesRef = firebase.database().ref('Stores/');
storesRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
  console.log("test");
 },function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the fetched values, they need to be extracted using [.val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) method.

From firebase documentation:

> firebase.database.DataSnapshot
>
> A DataSnapshot contains data from a database location.
>
> Any time you read data from the database, you receive the data as a DataSnapshot. A DataSnapshot is passed to the event callbacks you attach with on() or once(). You can extract the contents of the snapshot as a JavaScript object by calling the val() method. Alternatively, you can traverse into the snapshot by calling child() to return child snapshots (which you could then call val() on).

```
storesRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val().key); // change this
  console.log("test");
},function (errorObject) {
   console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: The test nor the val().key printed

Comment: Is reference correct? Try printing reference, ```storesRef.toString()```.